# Random ports above 30000 Open and Close

Tags: python, network-programming, port-scanning

I have been scanning my local host ports on python (using socket library) at intervals of 5 seconds and turns out random ports above 30000 open and close. Eg

```
[xxx, xxx, xxxx]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx, 36338]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx, 41389, 41703]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx, 41410]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx, 33350]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx]
[xxx, xxx, xxxx]
```

Is there any specific reason , or is the scanner faulty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those random ports are opened when you connect to a host, like when you connect to stackoverflow, your browser needs to open a port to connect to stackoverflow, but it is not listening for connections. The scanner is not faulty.

Comment: Thanks , didn't realize that.